# Windows 10 Sign Out behavior with multiple users

Tags: windows-10

I just installed Windows 10 and I'm confused by the new Sign Out behavior. I have multiple user accounts on this computer. Previously, in Windows 8.1, when I would sign out, it would bring me back to a main screen where anyone is free to Sign In.

But now, in Windows 10, when I sign out, it brings me back to the Sign In screen only for me. I'm using a picture login if that's relevant.

So how can I sign out and allow other users to easily sign in?

Seems like basic functionality. Can't understand why this is working as it is.

Comment: Are all the user accounts currently enabled?

Comment: Yes, I have 5 accounts on this computer. All accounts are enabled. It seems that if I switch to a password sign in mode, as opposed to picture sign in mode, then the other accounts are displayed on the lower left. But this kind of ruins the picture sign in mode. Uggh

Comment: You realize you can click on your name in the start menu to switch users right?

Comment: Yep. I realize that I can click on my name in the Start menu to switch users. That's how I'm able to Sign Out. But I don't want to remain signed in so that others can switch to their account. In general, I don't want the other users to use the computer under my administrator context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Upgrade to Windows 10 Anniversary Edition.

Microsoft finally corrected this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to password mode then you can select from the other users.
Its a really bad design, means switching between two users both using picture passwords takes three steps..

Answer (score 0):

It's a design choice. Seems that if the other users don't have picture logins, you won't see them on the picture login screen. It should still show the other logins, but take you to the other screen if they they don't have a picture login.